# Update database with javascript variables

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this script that determines the position of an element (x position, y position), I am trying to use ajax to send it to this update.php file and update the table.

```
this.addEventListener("load", doSomething, true);

function doSomething(e) {
    var myElement = document.querySelector("#myElement");     
    var position = getPosition(myElement);
    alert("The image is located at: " + position.x + ", " + position.y);
}

function getPosition(element) {
    var xPosition = 0;
    var yPosition = 0;

    while(element) {
        xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
        yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }

    return { 
        x: xPosition,
        y: yPosition
    };
}
```

This gives me a nice alert with position, but just need it so in update.php I can retrieve it easily like `$_POST['x']` and `$_POST['y']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the values to the "data" attribute in your AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/oneFolderFromRoot/update.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'positionX': position.X, 'positionY': position.Y},
    success: function() {
    }
});
```

You can check for your POST data like:

```
if (isset($_POST['positionX'])){
    $positionX = $_POST['positionX'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i had to make it position.x instead of position.X to work but defintely a big help!

Comment: Oh, haha. Looks like I threw my own Point notation in there :D